# I want to print both Arithmetic progression and Geometric progression simultaneously using only one for loop,but i can only able to print only one

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    char choice;
    do
    {
        int num, ratio,iter,firstno = 0;
        printf("enter the no of times\n");
        scanf("%d",&num);
        printf("enter the first num\n");
        scanf("%d",&firstno);
        printf("enter the ratio\n");
        scanf("%d",&ratio);
        int ap = 0, gp = 1;

        for (iter = 1; iter <= num; iter++)
        {
            switch (iter)
            {
            case 1:
                printf("AP : %d ",firstno);
                break;
            default:
                ap = firstno + ratio;
                printf("%d ", ap);
                firstno = ap;
                break;
            }

        }
        printf("\n");

        printf("do you want to continue(y/n):\n");
        scanf(" %c", &choice);
    } while(choice == 'y'); 
    return 0;
}
```

How to print both the sequence using only one for loop?
I used switch case inside for loop but I can only print the Arithmetic progression.
Can anyone help me out?
         Input: = 5 
        start from 2
        common difference 3
         (all above can vary, its users choice
Expected output:
AP : 2 5 8 11 14
GP : 2 6 18 54 162

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us a simple example of input and expected output.

Comment: Hint: using a switch/case here is totally pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a table to show both AP and GP using a single loop

here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    char choice;
    do {
        int num, ratio,iter,firstno = 0;
        printf("enter the no of times\n");
        scanf("%d",&num);
        printf("enter the first num\n");
        scanf("%d",&firstno);
        printf("enter the ratio\n");
        scanf("%d",&ratio);
        int ap = firstno, gp = firstno;

        printf("--------------------\n");
        printf("|  n |   ap |   gp |\n");
        printf("--------------------\n");


        for (iter = 1; iter <= num; iter++) {
            printf("|%3d |%5d |%5d |\n", iter, ap, gp);
            ap = ap + ratio;
            gp = gp * ratio;
        }

        printf("--------------------\n");

        printf("\n");

        printf("do you want to continue(y/n):\n");
        scanf(" %c", &choice);
    } while(choice == 'y'); 
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
--------------------
|  n |   ap |   gp |
--------------------
|  1 |    1 |    1 |
|  2 |    3 |    2 |
|  3 |    5 |    4 |
|  4 |    7 |    8 |
|  5 |    9 |   16 |
|  6 |   11 |   32 |
--------------------
```

Comment: no problem, please mark the question as solved so that others do not stumble upon this question